# Unwrapping Issues in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm having trouble using a value from a parsed JSON. Whenever I try to use a value from the dictionary it says it is Optional. It won't let me convert to int. Any help unwrapping the value and converting to int would be appreciated. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm just getting started with IOS and Swift. I show my trouble below with the value with key = "uso".

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String : String]]{

    for line in json{
    //unwrap it with if let.
        print(line)
        let uso = String(line["uso"])
        print(uso)
    }

} 
else {
    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")

}
```

This is my output:

```
["capacidad": "15", "uso": "5", "unidad": "sanfrancisco", "telefono": "num"]

Optional("5")

["capacidad": "15", "uso": "5", "unidad": "pediatricouniversitario", "telefono": "num"]

Optional("5")

 ["capacidad": "15", "uso": "7", "unidad": "sanjorge", "telefono": "num"]

 Optional("7")

 ["capacidad": "20", "uso": "4", "unidad": "himacaguas", "telefono": "num"]

Optional("4")

["capacidad": "20", "uso": "8", "unidad": "himabayamon", "telefono": "num"]

Optional("8")

["capacidad": "10", "uso": "8", "unidad": "sanlucas", "telefono": "num"]

Optional("8")

["capacidad": "15", "uso": "11", "unidad": "auxiliomutuo", "telefono": "num"]

Optional("11")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the comment line in the loop suggests pretty well what to do

```
for line in json{
  //unwrap it with if let.
   if let uso = line["uso"], usoInt = Int(uso) {
    print(usoInt)
   }
}
```

Type casting is not needed as the type `[[String:String]]` is known.

Or, if `uso` exists always and represents always a number

```
for line in json{
  //unwrap it with if let.
   let uso = line["uso"]!
   print(Int(uso)!)
}
```